# Setting an automatic sort order in a subForm

Tags: vba, sorting, ms-access

Upon opening the mainForm, I would like the subForm to be sorted by ascending date order. I have tried setting the OrderByOnLoad property from the subForm to true and specifying OrderBy with no success. Also tried the same on the main Form. My next approach was setting the OrderBy directly on the subForms code; tried following code on *Form_Load(), Form_Open(), Form_AfterUpdate()* with no luck:

```
Form.OrderBy = "Hora ASC"
Form.OrderByOn = True
```

Also tried with `me.OrderBy = Hora ASC` and `me.OrderByOn = True`. The only thing that gave results was using the `me.` variant on *Form_Current()*. But this came with another problem: Although the records where now sorted, I could only modify or even only move on the first of the records row and got this message upong closing the Form:

[image]

This is how the Form with the subForm looks like:

[image]

Any help would be gladly apreciated, thanks in advance !

EDIT: Maybe its important to note that I use a cmd with filter to open the Form. The code is:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "HorarioAlim", acNormal, , "[Base-Número]= '" & Me.txtCod & "'", , acNormal
```

Answer (score 1):

Your references to the subform in the main form need to be relative to the main form.

So in your main `Form_Load()` you would write the action like this:

```
With Me.subFormName.Form
    .OrderBy = "Hora"
    .OrderByOn = True
    .OrderByOnLoad = True
End With
```

Comment: I have written what you suggested on the mainForm's `Form_Load()` with no success. Turned the Form's properties on and off for OrderByOnLoad to see if anything changes... no luck.

Comment: What if you remove "ASC" and just call out "Hora"?

Answer (score 1):

I would sort the subform itself when loading:

```vb
Me.OrderBy = "Hora ASC"
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

Comment: As stated in the question above, allready tried that. Don't understand why the data is not sorting itself...

Comment: Then, I guess, something else is going on which we don't know about. Or leave out sorting of the subform and sort its recordsource.